Cmake linker fail but it is already compiled
Here is my project directories.
There is my Cmakefile, there is a linker fail
CMakeFiles/myTest.dir/testcases/echo_test.cpp.obj:echo_test.cpp:(.text+0x15): undefined reference to echo(int)
But there is already compiled echo.c.obj under build folder.
In my image, camke should link it according add_executable(myTest ${SOURCE_FILES} testcases/echo_test.cpp).
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
    project(echo-test)
        # GoogleTest requires at least C++14
    set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
        include(FetchContent)
    FetchContent_Declare(
    googletest
    URL https://github.com/google/googletest/archive/03597a01ee50ed33e9dfd640b249b4be3799d395.zip
    )
    # For Windows: Prevent overriding the parent project's compiler/linker settings
    set(gtest_force_shared_crt ON CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
    FetchContent_MakeAvailable(googletest)
        enable_testing()
        include(GoogleTest)
        file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCE_FILES
        "src/*.c"
    )
        set(HEADER_PATHS 
        "include/"
    )
    include_directories(${HEADER_PATHS})
    add_executable(myTest ${SOURCE_FILES} testcases/echo_test.cpp)
    target_link_libraries(
        myTest
        GTest::gtest_main
        gtest
    )
    gtest_discover_tests(myTest)

Here is my echo and echo_test
// echo.h 
int echo(int a);


// echo.c
#include "echo.h"

int echo(int a){
    return a;
}

// echo_test.cpp
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "echo.h"

TEST(TRANSPORT_TEST, simple_test) {
    EXPECT_EQ(10, echo(10));
}

I hope this build successfully.

The error message is NOT about compiling echo_test.cpp.obj file. The error message is about linking given file into the executable myTest. You need to read lines above the one you have shown.

You are right. I just want to point out that the c file compile sucessfully but linker fail (as title), thanks.

You have read the question about "undefined reference" error, haven't you? It explains possible reasons of such error.

@Tsyvarev Thanls, this link resolve my issue.
